# Android notification with RemoteViews - having activity associated with RemoteViews layout

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-activity, remoteview

I've been researching on how to create custom-layout notification using `RemoteView`.

So far, I am able to create a notification with `contentView` and `bigContentView` pointing to a `RemoteView` with a custom layout xml. However, what does not happen, is to have `Activity` (associated with custom layout) started when this `RemoteView` is created.

I've double checked and in my layout xml, it appears to have correct `Activity` class name:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".LLMNotificationActivity" >

..... the rest are standard layout items: images, buttons and text

</RelativeLayout>
```

In manifest file, right after main application main activity, notification activity is also added:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LLMNotificationActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I would expect when notification uses `RemoteView` for its content, that this `RemoteView` will launch activity that is attached to its layout definition. However it appears not.

Here is how I create a notification in main application `Activity`:

```
protected void startNoti() {
    if( noti!=null ) return;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();  

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_noti1);

    Notification.Builder notibuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    notibuilder.setContentTitle(" ");
    notibuilder.setContentText(" ");
    notibuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notibuilder.setOngoing(true);

    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti = notibuilder.build();

    noti.contentView = contentView;

    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);  
}
```

`LLMNotificationActivity` activity class is defined as usual:

```
public class LLMNotificationActivity extends Activity {
    .... etc.... constructor, some button on-click handlers, nothing spectacular...
}
```

Can anyone point to me what I am missing or if I have misunderstood what `RemoteView` can do? My understanding is that `RemoteView` should, once created, invoke activity associated with its layout. Or - is there some API I've missed that explicitly can set intent of the `RemoteView`?

What I have found so far are only setting content `Intent` which basically just launches an `Activity` once user touches notification. What I'm looking for is to handle touches to some of UI elements inside custom-layout notification, not to launch an `Activity` regardless where the user clicks on notification surface.

For example, if I have 3 icons (i.e. `ImageView`) in a `RemoteView` which notification uses, I'd like to be able to handle touch on each one of them. I can't imagine this wouldn't be possible as if it's not, what's the point of having `RemoteView` in notification?

Comment: XML attributes in the `tools` Manifest only affect the tools (i.e., providing the right theme when looking at the layout preview in your IDE based on the `tools:context` that is declared). They have no effect at run time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. XML was auto-generated by my IDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to associate the activity thought `setOnClickPendingIntent` to launch the activity from remote view as below...You can set any of the layout id in the `RemoteView` to click.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 RemoteViews removeWidget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.your_layout);
 removeWidget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_id, pendingIntent);
```

provide an `+id/layout_id` to the `RelativeLayout` your using.

If you have to launch the activity when user click on the notification, then you have to use `PendingIntent` as....

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContent(mRemoteControl);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNM.notify(1000,mBuilder.build());
```

For 3 buttons , You have to use create a custom `RemoteView` and use `PendingIntent`. some thing as below...

Here is the custom remote view i am using for one of my media player app. it has three button to handler click.

```
public class RemoveControlWidget extends RemoteViews
{
private final Context mContext;

public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.mediabook.app.ACTION_PLAY";

public static final String ACTION_PREVIOUS = "com.mediabook.app.ACTION_PREVIOUS";

public static final String ACTION_NEXT = "com.mediabook.app.ACTION_NEXT";

public RemoveControlWidget(Context context , String packageName, int layoutId)
{
    super(packageName, layoutId);
    mContext = context;
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PLAY);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext.getApplicationContext(),100,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play_control,pendingIntent);
    setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.pause_control,pendingIntent);
    intent = new Intent(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext.getApplicationContext(),101,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.previous_control,pendingIntent);
    intent = new Intent(ACTION_NEXT);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext.getApplicationContext(),102,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next_control,pendingIntent);
}
}
```

Comment: So does this mean that having activity associated with layout used for RemoteViews is not possible?

Comment: check my updated answer. hope this is what your looking

Comment: Thanks but as I've explained I do not want to launch an activity on a notification click. I'm looking at your second part, will report back with comment asap.

Comment: check my updated answer. use the first part. You can associate an activity with remote view. hope this is what your requirement.

Comment: I have accepter your answer, the last part to be precise - with custom RemoteViews class. I've however added a Broadcast instead of Service, and made my extended RemoteViews class to listen to specific broadcast message - so I can keep all UI-app logic within one object instance, instead of running/accessing a service. This was also because I needed to make changes to UI when user clicks on certain options. Basically my notification now runs like a small Activity :-) Thanks for your valuable input!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add`setContentIntent` to your **Notification.Builder** like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourLaunchedActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
Notification.Builder notibuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
notibuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Now, when you click on your notification, **YourLanchedActivity** will be launched.

Answer (score 0):

*you can implement the pending intent on click of remote view by doing the following
also note that
if you are trying to get a activity from the remote view then getAcitvity is used in pending intent
like
*

```
//i will create a simple method//
       //use return getActivity cause getting the bottom Activity
private static PendingIntent getActivityBottom(Context context) {
    clearNotification(context);

    Intent intentStartActivity = new Intent(context, BotomNavViewActivity.class);
    intentStartActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //intentStartActivity.addFlags(/*Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |*/ Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            2,
            intentStartActivity,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void clearNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

*Now if you want to get your service class the use getService in pending intent*

```
private static PendingIntent stopPlayer(Context context){
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MusicService.class);
    
           serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.stopService(serviceIntent);
           mContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_play, R.drawable.ic_play);
        

    return PendingIntent.getService(
            context,
            2,
            serviceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

*use the above method like this*

```
  //perfoam action on notification to go to activity
    mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notif_small,getActivityBottom(context));

    //for service
    mContentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notif_play,stopPlayer(context));
```